# Caliburn.Micro can action syntax and behaviour

Tags: caliburn.micro

Caliburn.Micro Can Action binding is being called with parameter(s), but not without parameter. I am pretty new with Caliburn.Micro. Can anybody explain the behaviour? I have already gone through the http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/introduction.

For below Xaml

```
<TextBox x:Name="YourName" />
<TextBox x:Name="Address" />
<Button x:Name="Save" />
```

This is working:

```
public void Save(string yourName, string address)
{
    MessageBox.Show( $"Your Name : {yourName}{Environment.NewLine}Address : {address}", "You have entered:", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}

public bool CanSave(string yourName, string address) => (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address));
```

This is not working

```
public void Save()
    {
        MessageBox.Show( $"Your Name : {yourName}{Environment.NewLine}Address : {address}", "You have entered:", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

public bool CanSave() => (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourName) && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TL;DR: Just use a Can-property instead of a Can-method and raise the `PropertyChanged` event whenever one of the preconditions might have changed.

There are **two ways** to implement Action Guards in Caliburn.Micro:

> When a handler is found for the “SayHello” message, it will check to see if that class also has either a property or a method named “CanSayHello.” If you have a guard property and your class implements INotifyPropertyChanged, then the framework will observe changes in that property and re-evaluate the guard accordingly.
>
> ---
>
> [All About Actions - Caliburn.Micro Documentation](http://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions)

### Using Methods as Guards

This is what you tried. It works great for Action methods that have parameters, because the guards are reevaluated every time one of those parameters change. There is no magic at work - actually, it just uses WPF data binding behind the scenes to bind the Action instance to the parameter values. As soon as the binding engine detects a change, the guard method will be invoked. That's the reason why it won't work when there are no parameters, and there is no way to easily trigger the guard by yourself.

### Using Properies as Guards

This is what you should be using in your case: Add a Get-only property, just like this:

```
public bool CanSave => (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(yourName) 
                        && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(address));
```

Then, whenever either `yourname` or `address` changes, just call:

```
this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CanSave));
```

This way, the framework will know that the value of the Guard may have changed and reevaluate it.

Comment: Still did not understand what magic that was, but it is working.. Damn I'm new to WPF in the first place and nothing has been more confusing than MVVM + Caliburn Micro + my business logic. Pretty sure I'm not adhering to the norms but maybe for later releases? Still, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a method with parameters you should do so:

```
<Button cal:Message.Attach="[Event Click] = [Action Save(YourName.Name, Address.Name)]"/>
```

Instead to enable/disable Save button, you should have the property YourName, Address and CanSave... And update the property (CanSave) every time the other changes (YouName, Address).

```
NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(CanSave));
```

I hope to be of help to you